# Property 'fullName' implicitly has type 'any', because its set accessor lacks a parameter type annotation

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I was following a course in JS. And he used the following code but when I added it its not working.
It returns undefined. 
The problem is at "set fullName"
This is the error from VS code:

> "Property 'fullName' implicitly has type 'any', because its set
>   accessor lacks a parameter type annotation"

The console gives undefined.

I googled it saw something with typescript version, but I am using the latest version that is provided with VSCODE the version of TypeScript is 3.9.0

```
class Person {
constructor(firstname, lastName, age, likes = []) {
    this.firstName = firstname
    this.lastName = lastName
    this.age = age
    this.likes = likes
}
getBio() {
    let bio = `${this.firstName} is ${this.age}.`

    this.likes.forEach( (like) => {
        bio = bio + ` ${this.firstName} likes ${like}.`
    }) 
    return bio        
}

set fullName(fullName) {
    const names = fullName.split(' ')
    this.firstName = names[0]
    this.lastName = names[1]
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "problem" lies in your tsconfig.

you have a file in your project root called `tsconfig.json` that has this line in it:

```
noImplicitAny: "true"
```

if you don't have a `tsconfig.json`, then vscode probably runs with a default config that has this option, and you can create a tsconfig to set the option.

this means that you can't write code where the type is implicitly any, you need to explicitly declare it's type or write it in a way where it's type can inferred. so you can either switch that option to `false` (NOT recommended) or you can explicitly declare your types

```
set fullName(fullName: string) {
```

and you probably want to get in the habit of doing this everywhere:

```
constructor(firstname: string, lastName: string, age: number, likes: string[] = []) {
```

just a personal note, course sounds out of date or not that great for typescript if they're coding with implicit any allowed.